# How to make wc accept a pipe file to take input from instead of stdin?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, exec

This is a homework problem. The task is to replicate the command: `ls | wc -l` in a C program using `execlp`, `fork`, and pipes.

**My Approach**

I think the problem can be solved this way:

1. Create a pipe file: `pipe.txt`
2. Create a child process using `fork()`

   - Map the `stdout` of the child process to `pipe.txt`
   - Execute `ls` using `execlp`
   - This puts the output of `ls` into `pipe.txt`
3. Inside of parent process

   - Map the `stdin` of the parent process to `pipe.txt`
   - Execute `wc -l` using `execlp` without giving any further arguments so it reads from stdin instead
   - Since the `stdout` of this parent process is still the terminal itself, so it should print out the number of lines on the terminal

**My Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
        int pipefds[2];
        int returnstatus;
        int pid;

        char argArr[30] = {'\n'};

        returnstatus = pipe(pipefds);
        if (returnstatus == -1) {
                printf("Unable to create pipe\n");
                return 1;
        }

        int file_desc = open("pipe.txt", O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT); 

        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0) {
                int copy_desc = dup2(file_desc, 1);
                execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
        } else {
                int copy_desc = dup2(file_desc, 0);
                close(copy_desc);
                execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
main.cpp blabla.cpp main pipe.txt
>
```

**Problems**

Two things that are wrong with this:

1. Since I set the stdout of the child to be the `pipe.txt` file, why does it still output on the terminal? NOTE: It does put the output in the `pipe.txt` file too. But why does it display on the terminal too?
2. It starts waiting for the user to provide the input? Shouldn't it get the input from pipe file instead of the user?

**Expected Output**

```
5
```

*if there are 5 files in the current directory

**Tried Solutions**

1. Using just the pipe: (Got a bad file descriptor error)

```
int main() {
        int pipefds[2];
        int returnstatus;
        int pid;

        returnstatus = pipe(pipefds);
        if (returnstatus == -1) {
                printf("Unable to create pipe\n");
                return 1;
        }

        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0) {
                dup2(pipefds[0], 1);
                close(pipefds[1]);
                execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
        } else {
                dup2(pipefds[1], 0);
                close(pipefds[0]);
                execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: A file "pipe.txt" is not a pipe, you should use the `pipe` function, see `man pipe`.

Comment: You do not need or want a named pipe.  You want an anonymous pipe.  Search for those terms and read.

Comment: I just noticed that your program contains `returnstatus = pipe(pipefds);`, but you don't use `pipefds`.

Comment: C++ uses classes and streams... this is not C++, please remove the tag.

Comment: @Bodo I don't understand how I can use pipefds instead of pipe.txt. I tried to do it using just the pipe itself but got a Bad File Descriptor error. I've edited the answer with the solution I tried.

Comment: @kronaemmanuel the pipe has two ends: an end you can read from (pipefds[0]) and an end you can write to (pipefds[1]) and your program gets them the wrong way around.

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child or parent. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, do so before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've posted the working code as an answer. I am closing the unused file descriptors in it before ```execlp()```. Are there any other file descriptors that I have not closed?

Comment: @kronaemmanuel Yes, there are many that still need to be closed.  The boiler plate code is `dup2(pipefds[0], x); close(pipefds[0]); close(pipefds[1]);..` Close them both. The one you want to keep has been dup'd, and you now have two of them, one of which should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the helpful comments.

The problem in the code is that I am not using pipes at all. I was doing all my work with a file that I created. So that was the basic problem.

Here's the new code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    // Step1. Create pipe file descriptors: pipefd[0] for reading from pipe, pipefd[1] for writing to the pipe
    int pipefds[2];

    // Helping variables
    int returnstatus;
    int pid;

    // Step2. Create a pipe with the file descriptors
    returnstatus = pipe(pipefds);

    // Check if pipe was successfully created
    if (returnstatus == -1) {
        printf("Unable to create pipe\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Step3. Fork to create a child process
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        // Inside the child process

        // Step4. Duplicate the file descriptor of the write end of the pipe and set it equal to the stdout of the process 
        dup2(pipefds[1], 1);

        // Step5. Close both ends of the pipe
        close(pipefds[0]);
        close(pipefds[1]);

        // Step6. Execute the LS command. It ouputs to stdout which we set equal to the pipe in Step4.
        // So essentially, we send all output of ls to our pipe 
        returnstatus = execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);

        // Error checking the execlp command
        if (returnstatus == -1){
            perror("Error executing execlp: ");
        }
    } else {
        // Inside the parent process

        // Step7. Duplicate the file descriptor the READ end of the pipe and set it equal to the stdin of the process
        dup2(pipefds[0], 0);

        // Step8. Close the both ends of the pipe
        close(pipefds[0]);
        close(pipefds[1]);

        // Step9. Execute the WC command. It takes the file as an argument usually but if no file is given, it will take
        // stdin as input. Since the stdin is the pipe, therefore it will read all the data from the pipe.
        // The output of the wc command is stdout which is the terminal for this process so we will get the number of
        // files/directories in the current directory as an output on the terminal
        returnstatus = execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);

        // Error checking the execlp command
        if (returnstatus == -1){
            perror("Error executing execlp: ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the child, you need to close _both_ pipe descriptors after you've duplicated the write end.  In the parent, you need to close _both_ pipe descriptors after you've duplicated the read end.  In more complicated scenarios (multiple stages in a pipeline; bi-direction communications with pipes), this is crucial.  Here, you can probably get away with being sloppy, but it is better not to be sloppy.  Also, you should report an error and exit if either `execlp()` call fails.  Again, here you won't run into much trouble, but runaway 'failed to exec' children can make life very difficult.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I've edited the code to reflect these changes.

Comment: nit: (not really a "nit" in my opinion, but rather a criticism of the first step toward the gaping chasm of horrible code).  error messages *must* go to stderr.  `printf("Unable to create pipe\n");` is a disaster which leads to hundreds of hours of debugging nightmares. This is not an exaggeration.  Software that spews random crap on stdout (or to the wrong logging level) that the developer believed was a useful diagnostic, when magnified by a number of instances at scale, are a tragedy.  `perror("pipe")` is necessary and sufficient.