# How to send stdout to shared mmap?

Tags: c, linux, posix, shared-memory, mmap

This is a homework assignment. The task is to replicate the shell command: `ls | wc -l` in C using shared memory with `mmap()` while following POSIX standards.

Here was my original approach to the problem:

1. Create a shared memory region `sh_mem`
2. Fork the process
3. Inside the child process:

   - Bind `stdout` to write to `sh_mem` somehow
   - Call `execlp("ls", "ls", NULL)`
4. Inside the parent process:

   - `wait(NULL)` for the child to complete
   - Bind `stdin` to read from `sh_mem` somehow
   - Call `execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL)`

**Problem:**

However, I could not think of how to bind the `stdin`/`stdout` to `sh_mem`. I did it with pipes and thought I could implement something similar here, but I couldn't find any ways.

Can you give me suggestions on how to solve this problem?

**Code: (Not complete)**

Here's my code that I have written so far but it is pretty useless right now. It just writes and reads from child and parent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char* p_msg = "Hello";
    const char* c_msg = "World";

    void* shmem = mmap(NULL, sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    memcpy(shmem, p_msg, sizeof(p_msg));

    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
        printf("Child reads: %s\n", shmem);
        memcpy(shmem, c_msg, sizeof(c_msg));
    }
    else {
        printf("Parent reads: %s\n", shmem);
        sleep(1);
        printf("after one sec: %s\n", shmem);
    }
}
```

**Possible Solution 1:**

I thought of another approach where I use a file to write and have a memory map to the file. But then I fail to see the utility of the shared memory if the file is being used to do the actual reads and writes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int returnstatus;

    // Create a file
    int fd = open("shmem.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, O_RDWR);

    // Create a memory map of the file
    void* sh_mem = mmap(NULL, sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);


    // Create a child process   int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
        // Inside Child process
        // Link stdout to file

        dup2(fd, 1);    

        // Close unused fd
        close(fd)       

        // Execute ls
        execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);

    else {
        // Inside Parent Process

        // Link stdin to file/sh_mem

        // Execute wc
    }

}
```

**Possible Solution 2:**

Suggested by @kaylum. Use `shm_open()` to get an `fd` to the shared memory.

I tried it but it doesn't work as I expected it to. It doesn't bind either the `stdout` or the `stdin`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int returnstatus;

    // Get the fd of the map
    int fd = open("sh.file", O_RDWR, O_RDWR);

    // Create a memory map of the file
    void* sh_mem = mmap(NULL, sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    // Create a child process
    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
        // Inside Child process
        // Link stdout to file
        dup2(fd, 1);    

        // Close unused fd
        close(fd);      

        // Execute ls
        execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
    }   
    else { // Inside Parent Process
        // Link stdin to file
        dup2(fd, 0);

        // CLose unused fd
        close(fd);

        // Execute wc
        execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
    }

}
```

Comment: Would knowing about [shm_open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) help?

Comment: @kaylum Oh, this looks interesting. So this is like a shared memory version of open(). Lemme see if this solves my problem.

Comment: Hmm.  I didn't think that the file descriptor returned by `shm_open()` could be used to perform I/O.

Comment: Mapping a file into memory and accessing that is not at all the same thing as using a shared memory segment, so I don't think your alternative idea satisfies the requirements.  My first guess at the intention of the exercise is that you are expected to use a shared memory segment in the usual way: as memory that can be directly read and written by both processes.  I am disinclined to think that using I/O functions to mediate access to the shared memory is the expected solution.

Comment: @kaylum, I tried using shm_open but I don't think it behaves in the way I want it to.

Comment: Stdout is not seekable, so it cannot be mmapped. [beeing a stream it has no defined size]

Comment: @JohnBollinger I had previously implemented this with the help of [pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60440048/6559455). The exercise says that I need to use shared memory instead of pipes this time.

Comment: @wildplasser I dunno if I understand this correctly, but I'm not trying to memory map stdout itself. I just want a shared memory space where my stdout goes in automatically.

Comment: That's pretty much what I supposed, @kronaemmanuel, and in no way is it inconsistent with my comments.  Shared memory and pipes are different mechanisms for IPC.  They have different usage idioms.  Use the appropriate idioms for the mechanism chosen.

Comment: @wildplasser Do you mean "being an unseekable stream"? If I `fopen` a writable regular filesystem file, then I have a seekable stream, right?

Comment: That does not preclude transferring data from a stream to a shared memory segment or *vice versa* by providing a pointer into the shared memory as an argument to `fwrite` or `fread`, or to perform a similar transfer with `write` or `read`, but POSIX does not, to my knowledge, define a way to wrap a buffer, shared or not, in a stream. Glibc offers an extension that does that, but I don't think even that quite meets your needs.

Comment: Does it have to be portable to all POSIX systems? If you can use Linux-specific functionality, use `vmsplice()`.

Comment: There probably is a trick in the homework question. Using a memory mapping instead of a pipe doesn't make any sense: just think, how would you implement `yes | head -n 100`? Other than by using the memory mapping as a circular buffer, and use another channel (eg. `flock(2)`) to synchronize the two processes (ie badly reimplement a pipe in userland).

Comment: @wildplasser Stdout may be seekable or not, just like any other file descriptor or stream. It depends on the actual file it points too. There's no restriction in POSIX against  calling `lseek` on fd 1 or `fseek` on the stdout stream. Also, you can obtain the file descriptor of a stdio stream with `fileno(3)`.